# Correct sql to linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm having difficulty converting this sql query to a linq query.  I'm trying to select all my orders with the order details attached to that order.  In sql the query is correct.  When I write it in linq is when everything goes haywire.  Here is my code:

```
                var result = from order in orders
                         join orderDetail in orderDetails
                         on order.OrderID equals orderDetail.OrderID

                         select new OrderVm
                         {
                             OrderId = order.OrderID,
                             OrderDetails = order.Order_Details.Select(x =>
                             new OrderDetailVm
                             {
                                 OrderId = orderDetail.OrderID,
                                 UnitPrice = orderDetail.UnitPrice,
                                 Quantity = orderDetail.Quantity,
                                 ProductId = orderDetail.ProductID

                             })
                         };

            return result.ToList();
```

that produces this result [image]

but in sql if I write

```
select 
o.OrderID,
o.CustomerID,
od.UnitPrice,
od.Quantity,
od.productid,
p.ProductName   
from Orders o
inner join [Order Details] od
    on o.OrderID = od.OrderID
inner join Products p
    on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
where o.OrderID = 10248
```

my expected out come is [image]

Comment: Can you provide the data for the two tables separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like from the way that you are using Order_Details in the nested object that the join already exists and that the join you are using is redundant.

```
 var result = from order in orders
                     select new OrderVm
                     {
                         OrderId = order.OrderID,
                         OrderDetails = order.Order_Details.Select(x =>
                         new OrderDetailVm
                         {
                             OrderId = x.OrderID,
                             UnitPrice = x.UnitPrice,
                             Quantity = x.Quantity,
                             ProductId = x.ProductID
                         })
                     };
```

Comment: I added the sql where just to slim down the result set

Comment: @TroyBryant ok, you can just rip it out if it's not necessary.  Does this answer the question or are you looking for more details?

Comment: sorry not exactly what i'm looking for.  Each Order has order details which should be a array of objects.

Comment: Ah, you are using "orderDetail" where you should be using "x" in your nested object.  I'm assuming since your relationships setup since you are using "Order_Details" in your order object. So if you get rid of your orderDetail join and switch out orderDetail with x that might get you a bit closer to where you want to be.

Comment: ahhh just got it